# Unknown hosts between 2 computers

Tags: home-networking, lan, hosts, hostname

I have 2 computers with Linux running on them:

- ip: 192.168.0.1 hostname: COMPUTER1
- ip: 192.168.0.2 hostname: COMPUTER2
- ip: 192.168.0.3 the router

I configured the `/etc/hostname` files with the corresponding hostname on both computers.
I also configured the `/etc/hosts` files:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost COMPUTER1  
::1         localhost.localdomain   localhost COMPUTER1
```

And I did the same thing with `COMPUTER2` for the second computer.
The IP adresses are provided from the router via DHCP. On both computers the DNS server is the router:
`/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 192.168.0.3
```

I can ping `192.168.0.2` from `COMPUTER1` and `COMPUTER2`.
I can ping `COMPUTER1` from itself but I can't ping `COMPUTER1` from `COMPUTER2`.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: did you add the names COMPUTER1 and COMPUTER2 to the other host's host file or the routers DNS zone? it looks like as it stands now, only the localhost can resolve COMPUTER1 or COMPUTER2.

Comment: I added them to the `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` files on both computers. And I don't know what the routers DNS zone is.

Comment: may be being pedantic, but to clarify, the host file on COMPUTER1 has a line for COMPUTER2 with the IP 192.168.0.2 ?

Comment: If you setup the IP and Default gateway properly, then it should work. Can you see if you have iptables on both machines are running or not?

Comment: whats your router model? if possible, adding the hosts to its zone is the best possible solution.

Comment: @Frank, I published the `/etc/hosts` file of `COMPUTER1` in the question. The `/etc/hosts` file of `COMPUTER1` only contains lines for `COMPUTER1`. Same thing for `COMPUTER2`.

Comment: IP and gateway seem well configured because I can use ping with IP. It is more an host name problem. iptable is not setup on any computer.

Comment: I have a freebox v6 router. How to add the hosts in a router?

Comment: Can you ping directly to IP?

Comment: if you want to use host files for name resolution, you must put the other computers info in as well. as for your router, I tried looking it up, but the only support documents I can find are in french, so I'm afraid I can't help you there. the hosts file is definitely the easiest solution since your LAN is so small.

Comment: it sucks if I need to add every computers IPs and names in every `/etc/hosts` of every computers of my network. Is there a way that computers send their names to other or at least to the router (which is the DNS server). About the french documentation, it's not a problem for me. Please post the link.

Comment: @Robuust yes I can ping the IP but not the hostname